# Can I control the list of chargeable connections in the IPP inside an Intuit App Center App?

Tags: vb.net, intuit-partner-platform

I am developing an Intuit App Center app using the V3 SDK written in vb.net.

Is it possible to get/control the list of connected users that is listed in the Reports section of the Manage My Apps area in the Intuit Partner Platform? Specifically, the area where you view your connections and are able to disconnect users so you don't get charged for that connection.

I would like to be able to control that list from within my application for billing purposes. I have heard that it is possible to manipulate the list programmatically but I'm unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should definitely be do-able, but there's not a specific API for it.

There are really 3 components to tracking this information:

1. *Have they EVER connected* - you'll know this already because if they connected they will have gone through the OAuth process on your website and you'll have a token for them.
2. *Are they connected NOW* - you can test this by making an OAuth request to any of Intuit's services - if you get back a successful response, you know they are currently connected, vs. if you get back a 401 error you know the token is expired/no longer good.
3. *Disconnecting them* - you can choose to explicitly disconnect a user (and thus no longer get charged for their usage) by using the [disconnect API call](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0060_auth_auth/0015_disconnect_api).

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I knew there was a way but I was unsure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

There is no billing API available.

You need to check it from the appcenter.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0050_managing_your_app/connection_report

Thanks